# Simplifying a RegEx using a backreference

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference

Consider the ECMAScript RegEx

```
/\s*((ABC|A)(/(ABC|A)+)*)\s*/i
```

which matches A/ABC

Using a backreference, I am trying to simplify it by rewriting it to

```
/\s*((ABC|A)(/\2+)*)\s*/i
```

but this only seems to match A/A

Why am I experiencing this behavior and can I use a backreference here to simplify the RegEx? (I am testing it online at http://www.regexr.com/)

Comment: A backreference does not mean to match the same pattern but the same matched string.

Comment: You are so right, Gumbo!  I misinterpreted that when reading about backreferences!  On a certain website, I found the following sentence which explains it all: "Backreferences match the same text as previously matched by a capturing group."  That's of course why I only match A/A!

So my question now seems to transform into "If there is a capturing group that appears in multiple places in your regex, is there a way to make your regex shorter"?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this is happening is because the new regex that you have will only `A/A` or `A/AA` or `A/AAA`, (any number of A's after the /). (Technically it'll also match `ABC/ABC`, or `ABC/ABCABC`)

The `*` after your `(/\2+)` capture group matches any number of the `(/\2+)` capture group. So unless you don't care what comes after the `A/A` (i.e. `A/AFOO`) then you could do `/\s*((ABC|A)(/\2+).*)\s*/i` which would match `A/A(whatever here)`, (i.e. `A/ABC`, `A/ADC`, `A/Afoobar`)

Otherwise, I'd recommend sticking with the original regex.